# Setting content orientation changes the dimming effect when popup appears

Tags: qt, qml, popup, applicationwindow

I have a screen with a popup that's supposed to be displayed when a user inputs an invalid parameter. However, when I deploy the screens to the embedded device, everything appears in landscape mode, clipping a part of the screen. To solve this, I added a `Page` element to `main.qml` with `rotation` set to `90`. This then serves as a parent for all the screens so they appear correctly on the employed device. However, this fix does not work with any popups. To rotate popups, I started using `contentOrientation: Qt.LandscapeOrientation` property under `ApplicationWindow` in `main.qml`. This has fixed the issue of popups not rotating, but the dimming effect is now rendering incorrectly, only blurring half the application window. How do I rotate the popups and keep the dimming effect intact?

EDIT 1: The platform is Odroid-N2 with [minimal image '20190806'](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-n2/os_images/ubuntu) for Ubuntu installed.

Comment: Which Qt Version do you use? Rotation should be handled automatically by os (Android/iOS). There is no need to do that manually with forced rotation properties.

Comment: I'm using 5.14.2. The screens are supposed to go on an Odroid device but they appear rotated if I don't force any rotation myself.

Comment: Okay, so your target platform is a Linux device?

Comment: That's correct. I downloaded the minimal image '20190806' for Ubuntu from [here](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-n2/os_images/ubuntu) which was then burned onto an EMMC. Sorry for having missed this detail. Let me know if there's any other info I should add to my question.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I have found to get things to work is customizing the dimming effect to force it to rotate.

```
// Controls dimming effect
Overlay.modal: Rectangle {
    rotation: 90
    anchors.centerIn: popupId
    color: "#66000000" // Opacity + Color of dimming effect.
}
```